# replace con pandas - dataframe - remplazar un string en todo el dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

estoy intentando utilizar y realizar mi primer proyecto, estuve haciendo un curso pero era más de temas estadísticos y no habia tanta aplicación a las librerias, de tal modo, hice ejercicios porque he utilizado python ya hace tiempo, y entiendo la sintaxis, pero la verdad no manejo muy bien las librerias para analisis de datos, así, estoy intentando eliminar del dataframe unos elementos como: "$" para despues volver los valores como un int, o un float, este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
df1m = read_csv("archivo_ejercicio.csv")

df1m2 = df1m.iloc[:,1:].replace("$","", regex= True)


ANO-2014    ANO-2015    ANO-2016    ANO-2017    ANO-2018    ANO-2019    ANO-2020     
ANO-2021
0   $ 8.258.014.655 $ 9.370.587.368 $ 10.865.531.432    $ 11.700.296.314    $ 
13.717.612.224  $ 15.053.610.576    $ 8.780.051.895 $ 10.179.038.000
1   $ 253.062.203   $ 306.329.082   $ 368.429.386   $ 426.940.968   $ 662.194.250   $ 
796.846.000 $ 559.716.000   $ 864.590.000
2   $ 2.370.773.024 $ 2.605.481.965 $ 2.976.564.291 $ 3.211.374.588 $ 3.881.301.106 $
```

En este ejercicio no me da error, ni me sale ninguna recomendación, sin embargo, la salida no es la esperada, me esta dando los mismos valores, y no se omitio el signo("$"), y no se como podría hacerlo, cabe decir, que la columna 0, indica otro tipo de dato que no deseo modificar, por eso inicio desde la columna 1, que seria ANO-2014.

Este mismo ejercicio lo intento con una sola columna y el código es el mismo, lo unico que cambia es la columna:

```
df1m["ANO-2015"].str.replace("$","",regex=True)
```

out

```
0        9.370.587.368
1          306.329.082 
2        2.605.481.965 
3          199.788.688 
4            8.940.064 
5          978.536.507
```

Así, les quedo agradecido si me pueden indicar como puedo remplazar elementos de mi dataframe para casi todo el conjunto de datos, omitiendo solo una columna, y como hago para que esto si se refleje, y cuales son los errores que estoy cometiendo, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo único que te hace falta es que debes escapar el símbolo `$`

```
df1m.iloc[:,1:].replace('\$','', regex=True)
```

Ya que `$` es un caracter especial en regex ([documentación](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regex-cheatsheet/))

Esto produce: (Utilcé los datos que pusiste en tu pregunta pero no estaban completos así que copié y pegué algunos)

```
    ANO-2014    ANO-2015    ANO-2016    ANO-2017    ANO-2018    ANO-2019    ANO-2020    ANO-2021
0   8.258.014.655   9.370.587.368   10.865.531.432  11.700.296.314  13.717.612.224  15.053.610.576  8.780.051.895   10.179.038.000
1   253.062.203 306.329.082 368.429.386 426.940.968 662.194.250 796.846.000 559.716.000 864.590.000
2   2.370.773.024   2.605.481.965   2.976.564.291   3.211.374.588   3.881.301.106   2.976.564.291   3.211.374.588   3.881.301.106
```

Comment: gracias si me funciono, no sabia, muy amable.

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.